# Apache Tiles - How to get HTTPServlet Request object in execute method of ViewPreparer

Tags: spring, servlets, tiles

Am using Spring MVC with tiles configuration and loading the Menus using ViewPreparer to load the menus into the application. I want HTTPServlet request object in the execute method of ViewPreparer for getting globalid set in HTTP Headers.

Please suggest how to get request object ...

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
public class MenuPreparer implements ViewPreparer {


public void execute(TilesRequestContext tilesContext, 
                  AttributeContext attributeContext) throws PreparerException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) tilesContext.getRequest();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Baadshah for your Quick reply ... Can you plz suggest which library to be used to get "ServletActionContext" ....

Comment: Hi I have added required JARS , but the HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest(); returning null ... Can u plz suggest exact jars required ....Thanks