# How to fetch HttpServletRequest in viewpreparer class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tiles

Am using Spring MVC framework and using view preparer to load the menu. I need to get the request object in viewpreparer class. For that am using the following code in view preparer

```
@Service
public class MenuViewPreparer implements ViewPreparer {


   HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
  // HttpSession session = request.getSession();
 public void execute(TilesRequestContext tilesContext,
         AttributeContext attributeContext) throws PreparerException {

         // MenuList fetches the list of all the main menus by calling the getMenuList() method present in MenuServiceDAOImpl
         // which is of type MenuDTO
         String user=null;
         System.out.println("Menu :"+request.hashCode());
         UserDTO userDTO = UserName.getUserName(request);
         user=userDTO.getUserId();
}
}
```

i need the request object in the execute method. but all am getting in request object in null. So getting an exception. Can anyone tell me how to get it?

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779374/apache-tiles-how-to-get-httpservlet-request-object-in-execute-method-of-viewprThis question has already been raised but no answer though.

Comment: but the answer is not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you have tiles together with spring security, then try this code:

```
    Object reqObj = tilesRequestContext.getRequestObjects()[0];
    ServletRequest reqq;
    if (SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.class.isInstance(reqObj)) {
        SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper schaqw = (SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper) reqObj;
        reqq = schaqw.getRequest();
    } else if(PageContext.class.isInstance(reqObj)){
        PageContext context = (PageContext) reqObj;
        reqq = context.getRequest();
    } else {
        throw new ImpossibleException("tilesRequestContext.getRequestObjects[0] has unknow type: "+ reqObj.getClass().getName());
    }
```

this work for me.

P.S. ImpossibleException is my custom exception for impossible situations. I do not know is it realy impossible but anyway in exception is all requred info. And this variant is definitely better than others.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ??

```
public class MenuPreparer implements ViewPreparer {


public void execute(TilesRequestContext tilesContext, 
                  AttributeContext attributeContext) throws PreparerException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) tilesContext.getRequest();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since tilesContext.getRequest() seems to be deprecated, I was forced to look for alternatives. The following worked for me :

```
Object[] requests = (Object[]) tilesContext.getRequestObjects();
PageContext pageContext = null;
HttpServletRequest request = null;
if(requests.length > 0){
     pageContext = (PageContext) requests[0];
     request = (HttpServletRequest) pageContext.getRequest();
}
```

Let me know if it works.